# CSS: changing position of elements

Tags: html, css

In my webpage, in header section I have this kind of code:

```
<header>
    <span>Test</span>
    <span>Test</span>
    <img src="http://serwer1417769.home.pl/foty/cyfrowe/LM358N/2.JPG" />
    <span>Test</span>
    <span>Test</span>
</header>
```

In a smaller screens than desktop I'd like to make it this img showing centered in a separate row and these spans showing below in one line. I don't have idea how to do that. I've tried to use a float property and now I'm trying position property but I managed only to center image; span elements are showing in one line but not below.

```
header {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
}
header span {
  padding-left: 2%;
}
header img {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
```

Here is a codepen where I tried to do that: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGgBeM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJVNBW

```
@positionLeft: 50%;
@containerWidth: 60%;
header {
  position: relative;
  width: @containerWidth;
  border:1px solid red;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  padding-top:240px;
  text-align:center;
  span {
    padding-left: 2%;
  }
  img {
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:0;
    margin-left:-135px;
  }
}
```

- Take the `img` out of the usual `static` flow by using `absolute`
  positioning.
- Align the `span`s to centre by using `text-align` as
  `center`
- Take absolute positioned `img` to center by applying `50%`
  left and half-its-width as correction using a negative `margin-left`
- Push the `span`s down below `img` by using a `padding-top`. Notice that `absolute` positioned `img` is not affected by this padding.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear on how this should look on desktop but `flexbox` can do that.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
.wrap {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 780px) {
  span {
    flex-basis: 25%;
    order: 2
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://serwer1417769.home.pl/foty/cyfrowe/LM358N/2.JPG" />
  </div>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
</header>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bdXBmL)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using bootstrap API, you can use following code snippet.
 Bootstrap API will help you to implement responsive user interface without much effort. Just try resizing browser. I hope this is what is you expect.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <span>Test</span>
    <span>Test</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <img src="http://serwer1417769.home.pl/foty/cyfrowe/LM358N/2.JPG" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <span>Test</span>
    <span>Test</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest Bootstrap - you beat me to it! :)